# Event binding with $(window) on dynamically created AJAX elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried multiple alternatives listed in other posts about event binding but it doesn't seem to be working. The code used to work with flat html, and it still works locally. However, when hosting it, it doesn't work 100% of the times.

The HTML and JS/AJAX code:

```
<ul class="cd-faq-categories" id="onderwerp">

</ul> <!-- cd-faq-categories -->

<script>
    //De categoriën ophalen uit het JSON bestand en weergeven in het menuvenster
    $.getJSON("vragenlijst.json", function (data) {

        // create a string of the object 
        data = JSON.stringify(data);

        // Parse the data
        const questions = JSON.parse(data);

        dataNew = questions.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.category < b.category) //sort string ascending
                return -1
            if (a.category > b.category)
                return 1
            return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
        })

        const newData = {}
        questions.forEach(item => {
            newData[item.category] = item
        })

        const liTemplate = (category) => `<a class="account" href="#${category}">${category}</a>`

        for (item in newData) {
            var child = document.createElement('li');
            child.innerHTML = liTemplate(newData[item].category);
            document.querySelectorAll('.cd-faq-categories')[0].appendChild(child);
        }
    });

</script>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var MqL = 1024;

    var faqsSections = $('.cd-faq-group'),
        faqsContainer = $('.cd-faq-items'),
        faqsCategoriesContainer = $('.cd-faq-categories'),
        closeFaqsContainer = $('.cd-close-panel');

    //update category sidebar while scrolling
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if ( $(window).width() > MqL ) {
            (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? updateCategory() : window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCategory); 
        }
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if($(window).width() <= MqL) {
            faqsCategoriesContainer.removeClass('is-fixed').css({
                '-moz-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateY(0)',
                'transform': 'translateY(0)',
            });
        }   
        if( faqsCategoriesContainer.hasClass('is-fixed') ) {
            faqsCategoriesContainer.css({
                'left': faqsContainer.offset().left,
            });
        }
    });


    function updateCategory(){
        updateCategoryPosition();
        updateSelectedCategory();
    }

    function updateCategoryPosition() {
        var top = $('.cd-faq').offset().top,
            height = jQuery('.cd-faq').height() - jQuery('.cd-faq-categories').height(),
            margin = 20;
        if( top - margin <= $(window).scrollTop() && top - margin + height > $(window).scrollTop() ) {
            var leftValue = faqsCategoriesContainer.offset().left,
                widthValue = faqsCategoriesContainer.width();
            faqsCategoriesContainer.addClass('is-fixed').css({
                'left': leftValue,
                'top': margin,
                '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
                'transform': 'translateZ(0)',
            });
        } else if( top - margin + height <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            var delta = top - margin + height - $(window).scrollTop();
            faqsCategoriesContainer.css({
                '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
                'transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY('+delta+'px)',
            });
        } else { 
            faqsCategoriesContainer.removeClass('is-fixed').css({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 0,
            });
        }
    }

    function updateSelectedCategory() {
        faqsSections.each(function(){
            var actual = $(this),
                margin = parseInt($('.cd-faq-title').eq(1).css('marginTop').replace('px', '')),
                activeCategory = $('.cd-faq-categories a[href="#'+actual.attr('id')+'"]'),
                topSection = (activeCategory.parent('li').is(':first-child')) ? 0 : Math.round(actual.offset().top);

            if ( ( topSection - 20 <= $(window).scrollTop() ) && ( Math.round(actual.offset().top) + actual.height() + margin - 20 > $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
                activeCategory.addClass('selected');
            }else {
                activeCategory.removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The HTML/JS/AJAX code generates a list of categories, that are clickable and refer to the section with the questions and answers in this category.

When scrolling through the page with questions and answers, the selected category has to change when scrolling to another category section.

How can I do this? I have tried taking it out of the `$(document).ready` function but this does not seem to be working. I have also tried changing out `$(window)` with `$(document)`,  but this doesn't seem to be working either.

Putting the `$(document).ready` function inside a function that is called after the `$.getJSON` function in the HTML/AJAX/JS code doesn't seem to be working 100% of the time either...

Comment: Well the code in `var faqsSections = $('.cd-faq-group'),
        faqsContainer = $('.cd-faq-items'),
        faqsCategoriesContainer = $('.cd-faq-categories'),
        closeFaqsContainer = $('.cd-close-panel');` needs to run AFTER you add the elements to the page. Impossible to select elements before they exist. So instead of calling that code on document ready, call it after you add it to the page.

Comment: Can I use `$(document).ajaxComplete` for this?

Comment: not sure why you would want too.

Comment: Okay, so this might be a stupid question, but how do I call it after adding it to the page?

Comment: I used `$(function() {}` now, is this a good alternative?

Comment: That is the same exact thing as document.ready

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the code AFTER you make the ajax request to fetch the JSON and build the HTML. So put the code into a function and call it after you are done building the HTML

```
function initializeCode () {  
  var MqL = 1024;
  /* The rest of your code in document.ready() */
}
```

And than after your Ajax call, use done and call the function

```
$.getJSON( /* your code */).done(initializeCode);
```

Comment: It actually didn't solve the problem. When testing it at home on a different computer, it still didn't work the first time I loaded the page. I had to refresh it multiple times for it to function. When I then refreshed the page again, it started malfunctioning again... :(

Comment: Do you know a different solution that could fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, having a separate JavaScript file containing my code caused some reliability issues. This lead to it not working properly (or at all) 100% of the times.

Putting all of my JavaScript code in the HTML file itself solved the problem.